# What is the integral of $\frac{\arcsin x}{(1-x^2)^{3/2}}$?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I was attempting this integral:
$I = \int \dfrac{\arcsin x}{(1-x^2)^{3/2}} dx$.
But I am getting the wrong answer.

My approach:

Let  $\arcsin x = t \implies  dx = \sqrt{1-x^2} dt$. 
So, $I =\frac{t}{\cos^2 t} dt = t × \tan t - \int \tan t dt = \dfrac{\arcsin x × x}{\sqrt {1-x^2}} + \ln (\cos t) + K $.

But apparently, the correct answer includes a negative sign in the first term, that is:
$I = - \dfrac{\arcsin x × x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}+ \ln (\sqrt{1-x^2}) + K $.

So, I want to know where that minus sign comes from.

Comment: I think something went very wrong during your LaTeX implementation...

Comment: You know.... you can preview your latex before posting. And you really should.

Comment: I made a small start in the title. With "copy-paste" you can try the rest?

Comment: Checking the original post, there seems to be a huge mistake in the above editing: the integrand originally was $$\frac{\arcsin x}{(1-x^2)^{3/2}}$$ . As it is now it appears as $$\frac{\arcsin x}{(1-x^2)^{3/\color{red}4}}$$

Comment: Sorry for this poor latex implementation. I don't know latex, so I pasted the syntax from other questions and this mess resulted. As you can see I have rectified it now.

Comment: @MrReality What you call "the correct answer" is for the function with the exponent $\;3/2\;$ in the denominator , as was **originally** in your post. As it is now the answer is the mess that appears in the answer below...

Comment: @DonAntonio, corrected that too. So, can you tell me which answer is correct: mine or the one with the minus sign?

Comment: @MrReality Apparently, no minus sign must be there...

Comment: As it stands now I don't think this question is inapt or the formatting is bad and so doesn't deserve this many downvotes. So can people upvote it to get it to "0" at least?

Comment: @MrReality You're correct. Sometimes people in this site get excited and a frenzy of downvotes begins. I already upvoted your question. +1

Comment: >> "*You're correct*" -            @DonAntonio, so you mean there is no negative sign in the first term of the solution, right?

Comment: @MrReality No, there is none...but you can check this simply differentiating without a sign and with the sign...

Comment: @DonAntonio, Thanks then.

Answer (score 2):

Whilst waiting for your LaTeX improvement...

$$\int \frac{\arcsin(x)}{(\sqrt{1-x^2})^{3/2}}\ \text{d}x = $$

$$ =  -\frac{\pi  \left(1-x^2\right)^{3/4} \, _3F_2\left(\frac{3}{4},\frac{3}{4},1;\frac{5}{4},\frac{7}{4};1-x^2\right)}{2 \sqrt{2} \Gamma \left(\frac{5}{4}\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{7}{4}\right)}-2 x \sqrt[4]{1-x^2} \, _2F_1\left(\frac{3}{4},1;\frac{5}{4};1-x^2\right) \sin ^{-1}(x)$$

Where $_aF_b$ are the hypergeometric functions, and $\Gamma(\cdot)$ is the Euler Gamma function.

Comment: I have rectified the poor formatting. Can you answer where the minus sign comes from, now?