# An integral I am unable to solve

Tags: calculus, integration

So I am a beginner to integral calculus, and I am trying to solve this question which is confusing me

It is $$\int \frac{\arcsin{x}}{(1-x^2)^{\frac{3}{4}}}dx$$

So far I have tried using substitution of $t=\arcsin{x} \Rightarrow dt=\frac{dx}{(1-x^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}}$. I can rewrite the denominator as $(1-x^2)^{\frac{1}{2}} (1-x^2)^{\frac{1}{4}}$ so that I can put in $dt$

And then I substituted $x=\sin{t}$ (so $1-x^2=\cos^2{t}$, which I can put in $(1-x^2)^{\frac{1}{4}}$ as $\sqrt{\cos{t}}$) back into the integral and it
left me with this
$$\int \frac{t}{\sqrt{\cos{t}}}dt$$

I don't know how to proceed from here, or whether I'm approaching this problem wrong.

Could someone tell me how to go about this problem and how to think about the strategy?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the integral of $\frac{\arcsin x}{(1-x^2)^{3/2}}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2698874/what-is-the-integral-of-frac-arcsin-x1-x23-2)